# Eigen matrix-vector multiplications with for_each

Tags: c++, templates, vector, foreach, eigen3

I want to handle sequence of matrix-vector multiplications with `for_each` loop.

So I made the code like this.

```
template <typename EigenMat, typename EigenVec>
struct MatVecMult{
    MatVecMult(const EigenMat& m){
        mat = m;
    }

    void operator()(EigenVec& v)
    {
        v = mat*v;
    }

    EigenMat mat;
};

//this is main loop.
Eigen::Matrix2d mat;
vector<Eigen::Vector2d> v_array; //very huge vector, i.e 1000000. 

MatVecMult<Eigen::Matrix2d, Eigen::Vector2d> functor(mat);
std::for_each(v_array.begin(), v_array.end(), functor);
```

Now the problem is the above code **requires me to specify template argument of `MatVecMul` functor**.

But rather than this, I want to make the code look more pretty like the following.

```
Eigen::Matrix2d mat1;
vector<Eigen::Vector2d> v_array1;
Eigen::Matrix4d mat2;
vector<Eigen::Vector4d> v_array2;

std::for_each(v_array1.begin(), v_array1.end(), MatVecMult(mat1));
std::for_each(v_array2.begin(), v_array2.end(), MatVecMult(mat2));
```

This code should work with any types of `Eigen::Matrix` and `Eigen::Vector`.
Is this possible?

Comment: Are the matrices/vectors all statically sized? Is all that changes the type (double, float, int, etc.) and will they always match (matrix <--> vector)?

Answer (score 1):

To complete Xin and Avi answers and completely reach your goal, you can rename the functor class, and make MatVecMult a free function. For instance, using Xin's solution and renaming his class to `MatVecMult_impl`:

```
template<typename MatType>
MatVecMult_impl<MatType> MatVecMult(const MatType &mat) {
   return MatVecMult_impl<MatType>(mat);
}
```

finally, another approach would be to replace the std vectors by Eigen matrices and do one larger matrix-matrix product:

```
Eigen::Matrix4d mat2;
Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, Dynamic> v_array2;
v_array2 = mat2 * v_array2;
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing you can improve of the `MatVecMulti` class is to make the `operator()` a template method:

```
template <typename EigenMat>
struct MatVecMult {
    MatVecMult(const EigenMat& m){
        mat = m;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T& v)
    {
        v = mat*v;
    }

    EigenMat mat;
};

// So now it can be used as

Eigen::Matrix2d mat;
vector<Eigen::Vector2d> v_array;

MatVecMult<Eigen::Matrix2d> functor(mat);
std::for_each(v_array.begin(), v_array.end(), functor);
```

Can the last template parameter of `MatVecMulti` be removed? It depends.

Because the multiplier data is stored in `MatVecMulti`, you will need the type of multiplier before you use it. That's why you have `MatVecMult<Eigen::Matrix2d> functor(mat);`

---

> But rather than this, I want to make the code look more pretty like
>   the following.

```
Eigen::Matrix2d mat1; 
vector<Eigen::Vector2d> v_array1;   
Eigen::Matrix4d mat2; 
vector<Eigen::Vector4d> v_array2;

std::for_each(v_array1.begin(), v_array1.end(), MatVecMult(mat1)); 
std::for_each(v_array2.begin(), v_array2.end(), MatVecMult(mat2));
```

If `Eigen::Matrix2d` and `Eigen::Matrix4d` shares a common base class, e.g. `Eigen::MyFakeBaseMatrix`, you can store/use the multiplier by polymorphism and turn constructor into a template method:

```
struct MatVecMult {
    template <typename prod_t>
    MatVecMult(const prod_t& m){
        mat = unique_ptr<MyFakeBaseMatrix>(new prod_t(m));
    }

    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T& v)
    {
        v = (*mat)*v;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<MyFakeBaseMatrix> mat;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the template parameters of `EigenMat` to deduce the vector type for `EigenVec`. The following compiles in g++, but not VS2013. I have not tested it for runtime issues.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/StdVector>

using std::vector;

template <typename EigenMat>
struct MatVecMult{
    typedef typename EigenMat::Scalar Scalar;
    typedef Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, EigenMat::ColsAtCompileTime, 1> EigenVec;
    MatVecMult(const EigenMat& m){
        mat = m;
    }

    void operator()(EigenVec& v)
    {
        v = mat*v;
    }

    EigenMat mat;
};

EIGEN_DEFINE_STL_VECTOR_SPECIALIZATION(Eigen::Vector4d);
EIGEN_DEFINE_STL_VECTOR_SPECIALIZATION(Eigen::Vector2d);

int main()
{
    Eigen::Matrix2d mat1;
    vector<Eigen::Vector2d> v_array1;
    Eigen::Matrix4d mat2;
    vector<Eigen::Vector4d> v_array2;

    std::for_each(v_array1.begin(), v_array1.end(), MatVecMult<Eigen::Matrix2d>(mat1));
    std::for_each(v_array2.begin(), v_array2.end(), MatVecMult<Eigen::Matrix4d>(mat2));

    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to deal with the alignment issues with Eigen static sized types using `std::vector`.